# Calculate lowest cost path through matrix in pure numpy

Tags: python, numpy, dynamic-programming

I am trying to calculate distances between time series'. For that i want to use dynamic time warping. To do that i get a matrix of the distances between each point in time for series1 and series2.

For that i already have the simply DP algorithm:

```
DTW = {}
dist_matrix = get_dist_matrix() # Returns a 2D numpy array

DTW[(-1, -1)] = 0
length = max(len(dist_matrix), len(dist_matrix[0]))
for i in range(len(dist_matrix)):
    DTW[(i, -1)] = inf
    for j in range(len(dist_matrix)[0]):
        DTW[(-1, j)] = inf
        DTW[(i, j)] = dist_matrix[i, j] + min(
            DTW[(i - 1, j)], DTW[(i, j - 1)], DTW[(i - 1, j - 1)]
        )

return (DTW[len(dist_matrix) - 1, len(dist_matrix[0]) - 1]) / length
```

However i have now been able to completely vectorize the calculations on both sides of this step, so the calculation of the `dist_matrix` and how to get to this step for all of the time series combinations that i am interested in.

And so now i would ideally like to also vectorize this step fully with numpy to get the maximum performance possible for the whole chain.